# How to create sub folders when creating file?

Tags: vb.net, file, stream, copy

i am making an application which involves reading chunks of an existing file and writing them to a new one... now, the problem is that the code i am currently using does not create subfolders and then file if a full path is given...

If i give it a path like this: C:\folder1\folder2\file.mp3 it gives an error because the folders folder1 and 2 does not exist, however, i would like it to create these subfolders if they do not exist while creating the file... thanks... here is my code:

```
  Dim bytesRead As Integer
Dim buffer(40096) As Byte

Using inFile As New System.IO.FileStream(arch, IO.FileMode.Open, IO.FileAccess.Read)
    Using outFile As New System.IO.FileStream(path & "\" & f, IO.FileMode.Create, IO.FileAccess.Write)
        inFile.Seek(StartAt, IO.SeekOrigin.Begin)

        Do
            If astop.Text = 1 = False Then
                If CurrentFsize - currtotal < buffer.Length Then
                    ReDim buffer(CurrentFsize - currtotal)
                End If

                bytesRead = inFile.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)
                If bytesRead > 0 Then
                    outFile.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead)
                    currtotal += bytesRead



                End If
            Else
                Exit Do
                Exit Do

            End If
            Application.DoEvents()

        Loop While bytesRead > 0 AndAlso currtotal < CurrentFsize
    End Using
End Using
```

Comment: I assume you are just starting on this code:  "If astop.Text = 1 = False Then" is bogus.

Comment: Yes, but astop is used in a seccond form when cancel is clicked, and checked inside the loop...

Comment: astop.Text = 1 = False is actually astop.Text = (1 = False). (1 = False) is always False. (1 = False) may be converted to "False" by VB but it will never be "True"

Comment: The if statement checks if astop.text is not 1, however, it could be inverted like if astop.text = then ' do stopping ' else ' do copy...

Comment: I suggest you add parentheses to make the logic a bit more clear: IF (astop.Text = 1) = False or IF NOT astop.Text =1 Then

Comment: I changed it to If astop.text = 1 then exit do else ... code ... as i suppose that would be faster. Do you think there is a preformance loss due to the textbox instead of a variable. I would rather use a variable, but i have not found any really good way of accessing variables between forms...

Comment: I doubt speed is an issue - if you are dealing with IO you've got lots of time. Readability is more important IMO. I astop.Text works at all you can certainly store the value in a variable.

Answer (score 2):

Yout should create the directories and subdirectories of `path` before creating the output file:

```
If(Not System.IO.Directory.Exists(path)) Then
    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(path)
```

Comment: Hmmm... i suppose i could create them first, however, I am looking for the most efficient way of doing this... The program might be working with a large number of files, so even performance differences of a few milliseconds do count...

Comment: Anyway, your program must create these folders, whatever method you use. In any case your code must call those folder-creating functions of system API under the hood. So you just can not win in performance with any other method.